# php while loop only displays one result for a mysql query across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with a while statement only returning one result. this is my first time trying to display product information from several tables and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. here is the code:

```
<?php
    require('./includes/config.inc.php');
    require(MYSQL);

    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tea");

    $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

    if(!$res){
    die('Could not complete query: '.mysqli_error($dbc));
    } else {

    echo 'Success!<br />';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $table = $row['category'];
        $inum = $row['item_number'];

        echo $table.' '.$inum.'<br />';

        $fetch = sprintf("SELECT sub_category, item_name, description FROM $table WHERE item_number ='$inum'");
        $fetchRes = mysqli_query($dbc, $fetch);

        if(!$fetchRes){
            die('Could not fetch: '.mysqli_error($dbc));
        } else {
            while($fetchRow = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchRes)){
                $subCat = $fetchRes['sub_category'];
                $iNumber = $inum;
                $iname = $fetchRes['item_name'];
                $desc = $fetchRes['description'];

                echo $id.' '.$subCat.' '.$iNumber.' '.$iname.' '.$desc.'<br />';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your while loop, you should be using the `$fetchRow` variable as the array from which to grab columns, such as 'sub_category'.

Comment: WOW don't know how I didn't notice that before... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

IS

```
  $subCat = $fetchRes['sub_category'];
  $iNumber = $inum;
  $iname = $fetchRes['item_name'];
  $desc = $fetchRes['description'];
```

Needs to be:  Res to Row

```
 $subCat = $fetchRow['sub_category'];
 $iNumber = $inum;
 $iname = $fetchRow['item_name'];
 $desc = $fetchRow['description'];
```